# Grails - How can I use JWT when login through UI using Spring Security Plugin

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I need to know If I can use JWT in grails application using spring security plugin. I want to generate token store it in cookie and than use it to login. Is it Possible through spring security plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest the rest security plugin. It has support for JWT and is straight forward to configure.
Be aware that there's a possible security issue with JWT (the user is serialized in the JWT token and deserialized without checking the existence of the user), I made a pull request for this.

Comment: I know about grails-spring-security-rest plugin. But I want to use jwt for Login through UI in grails.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What do you mean with use jwt for Login through UI?

Comment: Login form... like fb login

Comment: Spring security rest plugin does not restrict you to use the service with a form login. You can post an ajax request with the username and password to the JWT service, receive the JWT token and store it in your session. Actually JWT requires to include a http Authorization header with the JWT token.